# Missing session variables and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

My PHP code works fine locally but when I upload it to my host provider it is incapable of passing session variables and cookies. Both PHP configuratoins seem to be identical. I wrote two simple scripts (no bells or whistles included) as examples for anyone to analize and provide a solution, if possible. test2.php displays no values whatsoever. Will appreciate your help very much.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["testVar1"] = "Marlon";
$_SESSION["testVar2"] = "Brando";
setcookie("actor2","glenn ford",time()+60,"/");
header("Location: ./test2.php");
exit();
?>

<?php
session_start();
echo "Actor 1: ".$_SESSION["testVar1"]." ".$_SESSION["testVar2"]."<br>";
echo "Actor2: ",$_COOKIE['actor2'];
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the result?

Comment: Yes, it shows nothing except "actor1" and "actor2".

Comment: Hei, sorry for the long reply. If it's still not working, try to add this line on the beginning of your script 
`ini_get('display_errors'); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

This might gives you an insight on whats wrong

Comment: Samuel, I did that but got no errors so I am sure it is got to be a bug, not a real error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked with your provider as to whether they are allowing session state variables?

Is your hosting provider using apache? if so, I think they need to add the mod_session module. This is not installed by default as far as I remember.

Comment: My provider has been giving me the runaround. They are using Apache. phpinfo says sessions and cookies are enabled. Problem stems from a recent migration (of what, I don't know) Since then, sessions come and go randomly. This may sound stupid but that's what I see from my side of the equation.

Comment: Do you have the ability to try the code on another server? That way you can definitely determine if it is you or the provider.

Comment: Jerry, you gave me a great idea! I can but I hadn't thought about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Jerry, I just tried the scripts above on a different server. As expected they do work. I still don't have a clue to what to tell my hosting provider but anyway I think it's time to take my stuff elsewhere. Thank you all!

Comment: By the way, testing this issue I found out that session_status() fails. I had  introduced it to my code expecting to gain a little speed from not having to session_start() all the time. Stay away from it.

Comment: excellent! Glad I could point you in the right direction. Please vote this as accepted for me?